# Determining the dimensions of subspaces of M?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $M$ be the space of three by three matrices.  Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1\\-1&1&0\\0&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Interpreting $A$ as a linear operator from $M$ to $M$ (*rather than as a linear operator from $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^3$*), determine the dimensions of the nullspace and columnspace.

---

In [problem 11.2 c)](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/ax-b-and-the-four-subspaces/matrix-spaces-rank-1-small-world-graphs/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses1.11sol.pdf), how did we determine the dimensions of "nullspace" and "column space"?

Why are the values 3, and 6, when they should be 2 (pivot columns), and 1 (free variable)?

Comment: Note: Your vector space consists *of 3x3 matrices*.  You seem to be confusing the problem of looking at your vector space as $\Bbb R^3$ when you should be looking at your vector space as a subspace of $\Bbb R^{3\times 3}$

Comment: Remember that your space $M$ is nine-dimensional.  The linked pdf does a good job of explaining why the nullspace of the transformation $A$ (*when interpreted as a linear transformation from $M$ to $M$*) is dimension six.  What, apart from the slightly uncommon flavor, are you specifically having trouble with in understanding their solution?

Comment: @N.T Without bringing in pivots or row-reduction, do you understand what the "nullspace" and "column space" of a *linear transformation* are? Do you understand the difference between a linear transformation and a matrix?

Comment: I misspoke above, I meant to say column space has dimension six while nullspace was dimension 3.

Comment: I know the nullspace to be all non-zero solutions x or X (in our case) that result in Ax = 0 or AX = 0... 

I understand the column space to be the space spanned by the independent columns. The pivot columns would serve as basis and span R^r. When r = m, the column space spans the entire R^m space..

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, not sure I follow what you mean. By linear transformation you mean the multiplication of matrix A by another vector or matrix?

Comment: I think that's what confuses me, the vector space being a subspace of R^3x3...

Comment: The column space of a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^n$ would be the span of all of the columns of the corresponding (*or just the maximally independent set of columns*) of the corresponding matrix for the transformation.  "Column-space" is perhaps a poor choice of words for this problem though... "*Range*" might be a better label, so as to avoid the association with the columns of the matrix $A$.  The name columnspace is a result of the related problem for $\Bbb R^n$.  What is intended is to find the set of all possible outputs of the linear transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If all that is giving you difficulty in understanding the problem is the fact that the domain and codomain of our linear transformation is not of the form $\Bbb R^n$, but is instead a space of matrices $M$, we can redescribe the problem.

Reinterpreting a matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{bmatrix}$ in $M$ instead as a vector $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\\e\\f\\g\\h\\i\end{bmatrix}$ in $\Bbb R^9$, we would have our transformation $A$ as:

$$A\left(\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\\e\\f\\g\\h\\i\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}a-g\\b-h\\c-i\\d-a\\e-b\\f-c\\g-d\\h-e\\i-f\end{bmatrix}$$

From here you can describe $A$ using a matrix (*it won't be $3\times 3$ anymore, do you see what size it will be?*) and then use your familiar techniques of row reduction or whatever else.